# Why update query is failing with error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'

Tags: sql-server

This query is not working

```
update p
set p.TotalAmount =  SUM(pay.Amount)
FROM ##tmp t
INNER JOIN SMILAPPLICATION..Purchases p on t.ShoppingCartPaymentID = p.ExternalPurchaseId
INNER JOIN SMILAPPLICATION..PurchaseItems pit ON pit.ExternalPurchaseItemId = t.ShoppingCartID
INNER JOIN SMILAPPLICATION..Sessions s on t.SessionId = s.SessionId
LEFT JOIN SMILAPPLICATION..SessionPricing sp on s.SessionId = sp.SessionId
INNER JOIN SMILAPPLICATION..Payments pay ON pay.PurchaseItemId = pit.PurchaseItemId
GROUP By p.PurchaseId
```

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'GROUP'.

While this is working

```
update y
set y.TotalAmount =  x.Total
FROM
(
    select p.PurchaseId, SUM(pay.Amount) AS Total
    FROM ##tmp t
    INNER JOIN SMILAPPLICATION..Purchases p on t.ShoppingCartPaymentID = p.ExternalPurchaseId
    INNER JOIN SMILAPPLICATION..PurchaseItems pit ON pit.ExternalPurchaseItemId = t.ShoppingCartID
    INNER JOIN SMILAPPLICATION..Sessions s on t.SessionId = s.SessionId
    LEFT JOIN SMILAPPLICATION..SessionPricing sp on s.SessionId = sp.SessionId
    INNER JOIN SMILAPPLICATION..Payments pay ON pay.PurchaseItemId = pit.PurchaseItemId
    GROUP By p.PurchaseId
) x inner join SMILAPPLICATION..Purchases y on x.PurchaseId = y.PurchaseId
```

**WHY?**

Comment: Because aggregation functions cannot be used in `updates`.  That is how SQL works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is related to the way [UPDATE statement is working](https://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/645202-how-does-update-statement-work) behind the scenes and it will not allow any aggregation function:

> 1) You go to the base table. It cannot have an alias because an alias
>   would create a working table that would be updated and then disappear
>   after the statement is finished, thus doing nothing.
>
> 2) You go to the WHERE clause. All rows (if any!) that test TRUE are
>   marked as a subset. If there is no WHERE clause, then the entire table
>   is marked. The name of this set/pseudo-table is OLD in Standard SQL.
>
> 3) You go to the SET clause and construct a set/pseudo-table called
>   NEW. The rows in this table are build by copying values from the
>   columns are not mentioned from the original row to the NEW row. The
>   columns are assigned all at once. That is, the unit of work is a row,
>   not one column at a time.
>
> 4) The OLD subset is deleted and the NEW set is inserted.

I guess that, theoretically, `SUM(...)` with `GROUP BY` could be put in a pseudo table and copy the data, but I think `UPDATE` is meant to work (fast) for direct copy of data.

Comment: Very nice explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The `GROUP BY` is not supported in the `UPDATE` statement. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) for the complete syntax of the statement.

And it is supported in the `<table_source>` ([FROM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx))